# Is there way in Hudson to control People configure from command line?

Tags: hudson

Is there way in Hudson to control People configure from command line?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any configurations from command line, but...

There is a file under the main directory of hudson, config.xml that lists the administrative permissions that have been granded to users.
There is a directory called users again uder the main directory of hudson, where every user has a directory with its username. There another config.xml is placed with specific user configurations. The password is there as a Hash so I'm not sure if you can edit this property.

I haven't changed anything in these files... so, I don't know if this is something that can help you...

Comment: Instead of changing files and reloading them (might even require a restart) krvladislav should check into the remote API.